# How to simplify or make a repetitive code more efficient?

Tags: c, openssl

From the sample of code below you can observe that first function 1 (concat_1) is almost identical to the function 2(concat_2). The only difference is that 1 line extra which is SHA512_Update(&c, d, strlen((char*)d)).

My question is how to make these functions into 1, so that the code will not repeat. I believe, the difference in 1 line is waste of resources, and it should be fixed.

Note: each function requires a support of openssl library in order to reproduce the code.

```
uint8_t md[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
uint8_t a[] = "a";
uint8_t b[] = "b";
uint8_t x[] = "x";
uint8_t d[] = "d";


void concat_1(uint8_t *md, uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b, uint8_t *x)
{
    SHA512_CTX c;
    SHA512_Init(&c);

    SHA512_Update(&c, a, strlen((char*)a);
    SHA512_Update(&c, b, strlen((char*)b);
    SHA512_Update(&c, x, strlen((char*)x);

    SHA512_Final(md, &c);

}

void concat_2(uint8_t *md, uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b, uint8_t *x, uint8_t *d)
{
    SHA512_CTX c;
    SHA512_Init(&c);

    SHA512_Update(&c, a, strlen((char*)a);
    SHA512_Update(&c, b, strlen((char*)b);
    SHA512_Update(&c, x, strlen((char*)x));
    SHA512_Update(&c, d, strlen((char*)d));

    SHA512_Final(md, &c);

}
```

Comment: Given `uint8_t d`, do you realize what `strlen((char*)d)` is going to do?

Comment: `concat_2` can be generalized by changing `SHA512_Update(&c, d, strlen((char*)d));` to `if (d) SHA512_Update(&c, d, strlen((char*)d));`, after which the body of `concat_1` can be changed to `concat_2(md, a, b, x, NULL);`. The routines can be further generalized to `void concat_general(uint8_t *md, foo bar)`, where `foo bar` supplies a list of `uint8_t` pointers in some chosen format (could be more than one parameter, a structure containing a length and a pointer to `uint8_t *`, a null-terminated list, a variable argument list ending with `NULL`, or more).

Comment: Andrew Henle good point! I'll change to something like it: sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint8_t)

Comment: @mhibert: No, the problem is you declared the parameter as `uint8_t d` instead of `uint8_t *d`. Presumably, all the parameters should be `uint8_t *`, not `uint8_t`. And you must use `strlen` or supply their lengths when calling the function; `sizeof d / sizeof(uint8_t)` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize the routine using variable argument lists:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void concat(uint8_t *md, const uint8_t *x,...)
{
    SHA512_CTX c;
    SHA512_Init(&c);

    // Create and initialize a va_list to access the arguments.
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, x);

    // Continue while arguments are not null.
    while (x)
    {
        // Update with current argument’s text.
        SHA512_Update(&c, x, strlen((const char *) x));

        // Get next argument.
        x = va_arg(ap, const uint8_t *);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    SHA512_Final(md, &c);
}
```

Then you can call it with a `NULL` terminated list of arguments:

```
concat(md, a, NULL);
concat(md, a, b, c, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an argument specifying which of the two cases you want.

```c
void concat(int is_type_2, uint8_t *md, uint8_t *a, uint8_t b, uint8_t *x, uint8_t *d)
{
    SHA512_CTX c;
    SHA512_Init(&c);

    SHA512_Update(&c, a, strlen((char*)a));
    SHA512_Update(&c, b, strlen((char*)b));
    SHA512_Update(&c, x, strlen((char*)x));

    if (is_type_2)
        SHA512_Update(&c, d, strlen((char*)d));

    SHA512_Final((uint8_t*)md, &c);

}
```

And then add a couple of macros so that you can still call `concat_1` and `concat_2` just as before the merging:

```c
#define concat_1(...) concat(0, __VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define concat_2(...) concat(1, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if i will have more than 2 functions like 10 ? Then following your logic, I need to define 10 different macros?  for 100 - 100 macros?

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to call `concat_x` you must create the corresponding macro. If the number of functions becomes a lot you might want to just use a parameter to select which function to use and make it variadic so that you can have any number of parameters. Of course, this increase the complexity of the code.

Comment: What about a `NULL` check for `d` instead of an extra parameter?

Comment: That's absolutely fine if the second function cannot have a NULL d. NULL has usually value 0, therefore if concat_2 cannot have d ==  0 you can use that.

Comment: If you don't check for `NULL` you will call `strlen` with a `NULL` pointer and feed `NULL` into `SHA512_update` which is probably not the desired behaviour. Adding a  0 byte to the hash is OK but a`NULL` pointer is probably not.

Comment: ok, then it's fine to just check d instead of having that extra parameter